# How do I pass data between activities in Windows Workflow?

Tags: .net, data-binding, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I'm not completely sure I understand the workflow way of doing things, but if it's a pipeline n filter style model I should be able to pass data (even strings) from one activity to another.

Does anyone know how to do this? Bonus points for a video!

I hope this is possible. If WF were the same as my idea of it then it would be extremely useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Method 1 (Design- and run-time): Activity databinding

You can bind the dependency properties of an activity to the properties of another activity. See

- [Activity Binding in Windows Workflow Foundation](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3656966).
- [Enabling Activity Data Binding](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/36317/0/page/6)

#### Method 2 (Run-time): Find an activity from the activity tree

See

- Paragraph "Workflow Development" of the article [ActivityExecutionContext in Workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163414.aspx).
- [Binding to Activity Dependency Property in Code Activity](http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3880975&SiteID=1)